# Node.JS, HAproxy and Socket.IO through NGINX, app sits in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, subdirectory, haproxy

I've been trying for hours and have read what this site and the internet have to offer. I just can't quite seem to get Socket.IO to work properly here. I know nginx by default can't handle Socket.IO however, HAproxy can. I want nginx to serve the Node apps through unix sockets and that works great. Each have a sub directory location set by nginx, however, now I need Socket.IO for the last app and I'm at a loss of configuring at this point.

I have the latest socket.io, HAproxy 1.4.8 and nginx 1.2.1. Running ubuntu.

So reiterating, I need to get socket.io working though nginx to a node app in a subdirectory, ex: localhost/app/.

```
Diagram:
WEB => HAproxy => Nginx => {/app1 app1, /app2 app2, /app3 app3}
```

Let me now if I can offer anything else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to get "get socket.io working though nginx". Instead you just route HAProxy directly to Socket.IO (without Nginx in the middle).

I recommend you checkout the following links:

- https://gist.github.com/1014904
- http://blog.mixu.net/2011/08/13/nginx-websockets-ssl-and-socket-io-deployment/

Comment: The reason that I want to is so I can keep 3 apps running on port 80, but proxy them from a unix socket. So if there is a way to configure it, or a similar option, I'd be all ears for it. But thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: I see what you mean @YorkshireKev had a great example, but you gave me some sources. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Haproxy on port 80 to front several node.js apps running on different ports.

E.g.

URL:80/app1 -> haproxy -> node app1:8080

URL:80/app2 -> haproxy -> node app2:8081

URL:80/app3 -> haproxy -> node app3:8083

UPDATE:

The following is an example HAPROXY configuration that routes requests made to `http://server:80/hello` to `localhost:20001` and `http://server:80/echo` to `localhost:20002`

```
backend hello
    server hellosvr 127.0.0.1:20002

backend echo
    server echosvr 127.0.0.1:20001

frontend http_in
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1  # stunnel already adds the header
    bind *:80
    acl rec_hello path_beg /hello/
    use_backend hello if rec_hello
    acl rec_echo path_beg /echo
    use_backend echo if rec_echo
```

Comment: I WANT TO DO THIS! How do I do this?!

Comment: Sorry @ThomasReggi I don't know how I missed you're comment. I guess you've either figured it our or moved on by now... But for the benefit of future googlers I'll add a working extract from a HAPROXY configuration that routes /echopage and /hello to different resources.